# Can i standardize/convert the data in datetime to have the same "minutes"?

Tags: sas

I am a SAS developer using SAS Data Integration Studio.

Currently i have a scenario where data in many excel tabs are having different time value(minutes). For example

```
Tab A will have datetime
2010-Jan-01 01:00:00
2010-Jan-02 01:00:00
2010-Jan-03 01:00:00

Tab B will have datetime below:
2010-Jan-01 01:25:00
2010-Jan-02 01:25:00
2010-Jan-03 01:25:00
```

Do take note that table A and table B will have different columns apart from the SAME DATETIME (but not the minutes).

When i merge these 2 tables, i want to ignore the minutes, or rather standardize it to 01:00:00.

Is there a way to do so?

Currently, if i were to merge these 2 tables, i will have "Duplicate"(i mean same day but different record/result due to different minutes).

Imagine in table A, i have a column called Age
Table B, i have a column called Net Worth.

When i merge this 2 tables, I am expecting the table to have 1 single row record of 2010-Jan-01 01:00:00 with Age and Net worth.

However, when datetime does not match, they will have a new record with Age containing value but Blank Net worth or likewise.

Seeking for your help on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

You can truncate to the nearest hour using the `intnx` function before matching:

```
data _null_;
  mydatetime = datetime();
  mydatehour = intnx('dthour',mydatetime, 0, 'b');
  put mydatetime= is8601dt. / mydatehour= is8601dt.;
run;
```

Comment: Funny that 'dthour' is accepted as an interval, since it's the same thing as 'hour'.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [`DATEPART(datetime)`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000245883.htm)

Example:

```
data _null_;
   conn='01feb94:8:45'dt;
   servdate=datepart(conn);
    dhms = dhms(datepart(conn),hour(conn),0,0);
put  dhms datetime.;;
run;
```

result in log

```
01FEB94:08:00:00
```